# Convergence in Probability Proof

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show the following:

Let $X_1, X_2, . . .$ be $U(0, 1)$-distributed random variables. Show that
$max_{1\leq k\leq n}X_{k} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ in probability.

I am not sure where to start.  I know that to show convergence in probability I need that $\forall \epsilon > 0 , P(|X_n - X|) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but I can't figure out how to tackle applying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent and $X_i \sim U(0,1)$ for each $i$ then $f_{X_i}(x)=1 I_{[0,1]}(x)$ and $F_{X_i}(x)=x$, but we need to find the distribution of $X_{(n)}=\max(X_1,...X_n)$ and that is $$F_{X_{(n)}}(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n F_{X_i}(x)=x^n$$
Now to show convergence in probability we note that for $\epsilon > 0$,

$$
\begin{align}
P(|X_{(n)}-1|\leq\epsilon) &= P(1 - X_{(n)} \leq \epsilon) \\
&= P(X_{(n)} \geq 1 - \epsilon) \\
&= 1 - P(X_{(n)} < 1 - \epsilon) \\
&= 1 - (1 - \epsilon)^n \\
&\to 1,
\end{align}
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Shouldn't $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|X_{(n)}-1|\leq\epsilon)=0$ in order for $X_{(n)}$ to converge in probability to 1?

Comment: No, the maximum should be close to one with high probability.  $|X_{(n)} - 1| \leq \epsilon$ means it's close to one.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:  once you've shown $F_{X_{(n)}}(x) = x^n$ for $x \in [0, 1]$ (which John has already done), then we have $F_{X_{(n)}}(x) \to I_{[1, \infty)}(x)$ at all continuity points of $I_{[1, \infty)}(x)$.  But $I_{[1, \infty)}(x)$ is the distribution function for a random variable degenerate at 1 and therefore $X_{(n)} \to 1$ in distribution, which implies convergence in probability since the limiting random variable is constant.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that if $n$ is large enough, then it is very likely that the largest of the random variables $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ is going to be close to $1$.

Since the random variables are all between $0$ and $1$ you want to show that it is **unlikely** that *all* of the differences $(1-X_{k})$ are far from zero. $$1-(\max_{1\leq k \leq n}X_{k})= \min_{1\leq k \leq n}(1-X_{k}) \quad \Rightarrow \quad 0\leq\mathbb{P}(\min_{1\leq k \leq n}(1-X_{k}) > \varepsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(\cap_{k=1}^{n}\{1-X_{k} >\varepsilon\})= \prod_{1\leq k \leq n}\mathbb{P}(1-X_{k} > \varepsilon) = (1-\varepsilon)^{n}\ .$$ If you choose $n$ large enough you can make $(1-\varepsilon)^{n}$ as close to $0$ as you like, thus showing that it is unlikely that *all* of the differences $(1-X_{k})$ are far from zero.